# Extract page and page number with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract page and page number from the URL with regex.
There are couple of variations of page number:

```
fghghdsfs/page4
fghghdsfs/page-4
sfgsfgsfg/page=4
hteheth/page-4/
dhdghgd/page=4/
dghdghdh/page/4/
dghdghdh/page/4
fghghdsfs?page4
dhdghd?page-4
dghdg?page-4/
eyeyt?page=4
etyetyet?page=4/
nvnndgnd?page/4/
dghdghdh/page/4
```

Number of page should have between 1 and 3 digits.

I have tried with this regex, but I have a problem with identifying `/`:

```
(=|\?|\/)(page)(_|-|=|\d{1,3}|\/)
```

Comment: Which problem do you have with identifying `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the regex you have:

1. `\d{1,3}` is inside the parentheses. You're saying: `page` followed by *either* a separator *or* by the page number. Put it after the parentheses, and make it a capture group so you can extract it later.
2. The group with separators is required, so `page4` does not match. Put a `?` after the group.

Fixing those:

`(=|\?|\/)(page)(_|-|=|\/)?(\d{1,3})`

[See it in action on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gdpDkB/1).

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```sh
[=?/]page[_=/-]?(\d{1,3})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GAisUf/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[=?/]`: Match `=` or `?` or `/`
- `page`: Match string `page`
- `[_=/-]?`: *Optionally* match `_` or `=` or `/` or `-`
- `(\d{1,3})`: Match 1 to 3 digits

Comment: I removed the capture group, and then we basically have the same answers. I would go for this answer.